# How to extract port number from /etc/services file

Tags: sockets, unix, networking

How will client process extract the port number with not a well known port on which server process is working.
In Unix we have file /etc/services contain entries like
for Ex.
netperf 12865/udp
netperf 12865/tcp
How the client will extract the port number 12865 from this file (/etc/services) and begin the communication? Is there any specific function which will do this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way is to call [getservbyname()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29035/getservent-3socket.html). Note that the service definition is not necessarily in the `/etc/service` file but might be located in a shared base like `NIS` or `LDAP`.